# ¿Cómo aplicar el principio de inversión de dependencias en C++?

Tags: c++, interface, clase-abstracta

Estoy aprendiendo el principio de inversión de dependencias, el cual dice que el código debe depender de abstracciones en lugar de depender de clases concretas y lo he aplicado en C++ con exito.

```
#include <iostream>

class IPersistence{
public:
    virtual void save(int entity)    = 0;
    virtual int get(int id)          = 0;
    virtual void update(int entity)  = 0;
    virtual void delete_(int entity) = 0;
    virtual ~IPersistence() = default;
};

class Sqlite : public IPersistence{
public:
    void save(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha guardado en la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
    int get(int id) override{
        return id;
    }
    void update(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha actualizado en la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
    void delete_(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha eliminado de la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
};

class MySql : public IPersistence{
public:
    void save(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha guardado en la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
    int get(int id) override{
        return id;
    }
    void update(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha actualizado en la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
    void delete_(int entity) override{
        std::cout<<"el dato "<<entity<<" se ha eliminado de la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
};

class DataBase{
    IPersistence *dataBase_;
public:
    DataBase(IPersistence *dataBase):dataBase_{dataBase}{};
    ~DataBase(){ delete dataBase_; }

    void save(int entity)   { dataBase_->save(entity);    }
    int get(int id)         { return dataBase_->get(id);  }
    void update(int entity) { dataBase_->update(entity);  }
    void delete_(int entity){ dataBase_->delete_(entity); }
};

int main(){
    DataBase db(new MySql);

    db.save(12345);

    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, como la interfaz está diseñada para recibir parámetros int me he dado cuenta de que no consigo la flexibilidad que se supone, me otorga la inversión de dependencias, ya que este diseño funciona solo con ese tipo de dato (int), ¿Tengo que replantearme el diseño como por ejemplo hacer una interfaz por cada tipo, pero siento que esa no es la idea o hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?.

Comment: puedes usar la sobrecarga de funciones o usar templates para hacer todo más flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuando con la respuesta de [@antonio-trujillo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/575338/142959), con las plantillas no es necesario que uses polimorfismo puedes usar el "duck typing" o "interfaces estáticas" de c++ así mira:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sqlite {
public:
    using type = int;
    void save(int entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha guardado en la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
    int get(int id) {
        return id;
    }
    void update(int entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha actualizado en la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
    void delete_(int entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha eliminado de la base de datos sqlite\n";
    }
};

class MySql {
public:
    using type = std::string;
    void save(std::string entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha guardado en la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
    std::string get(int id) {
        return "datos de la entidad con id " + std::to_string(id);
    }
    void update(std::string entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha actualizado en la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
    void delete_(std::string entity) {
        std::cout << "el dato " << entity << " se ha eliminado de la base de datos mysql\n";
    }
};
```

La interfaz aquí seria cualquier clase que tenga las funciones miembro save, get, update, delete_ y un typedef "type" que defina el tipo de parámetro de las funciones

```
template<class T>
class DataBase{
    using type = typename T::type;
    T& dataBase_;
public:
    // sinceramente no veo buena idea que pases un puntero al 
    // constructor de database y luego esta en su destructor haga
    // delete de el, ya que no es database quien crea la memoria
    // al cual apunta el puntero, una referencia esta bien, la memoria
    // se crea y destruye automáticamente
    DataBase(T& dataBase) : dataBase_{ dataBase } { };
    //~DataBase(){ delete dataBase_; }

    void save(type entity)   { dataBase_.save(entity);    }
    type get(int id)         { return dataBase_.get(id);  }
    void update(type entity) { dataBase_.update(entity);  }
    void delete_(type entity){ dataBase_.delete_(entity); }
};

int main(){
    Sqlite sqlite { };
    DataBase<Sqlite> db1(sqlite);
    db1.save(12345); // el dato 12345 se ha guardado en la base de datos sqlite

    MySql mysql { };
    DataBase<MySql> db2(mysql);
    db2.save("54321"); // el dato 54321 se ha guardado en la base de datos mysql

    return 0;
}
```

PD: desde el estándar de c++17 se tiene [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) que sirve para deducir el tipo de argumento de la plantilla de la clase entonces el código del main quedaría así:

```
int main(){
    Sqlite sqlite { };
    DataBase db1(sqlite); // se deduce a DataBase<Sqlite>
    db1.save(12345); // el dato 12345 se ha guardado en la base de datos sqlite

    MySql mysql { };
    DataBase db2(mysql);  // se deduce a DataBase<MySql>
    db2.save("54321"); // el dato 54321 se ha guardado en la base de datos mysql

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesante, es todo un descubrimiento para mí, no conocía este segundo mecanismo que tiene C++ para lograr el mismo resultado que si usáramos el polimorfismo de toda la vida, además, por lo que veo las templates le dan mucho juego a C++ ya que se pueden usar tanto para funciones, clases y clases abstractas (interfaces), lo que permitiría solucionar el problema a mi pregunta, pero eso de usar el duck typing junto a las templates me da la impresión de que nos ahorramos el costo en memoria que conlleva usar “polimorfismo no estático”.